# Fill NaN values based on condition in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan, subtraction

I have the below dataframe:

```
data = [['1', 'Construction', '', '01/02/2022', '01/06/2022', '1', 'No'], ['N/A', 'Level Site', 'Construction', '01/02/2022', '01/02/2022', '2', 'No'], ['3', 'Foundation', '', '01/03/2023', '01/06/2023', '1', 'Yes'],['2', 'Lay Foundation', 'Construction>Foundation', '01/03/2022', '01/04/2022', '3', 'No'], ['N/A', 'Prepare land for foundation', 'Construction>Foundation', '01/05/2022', '01/06/2022', '3', 'No'],['2', 'Building Envelope', '', '01/07/2023', '01/16/2023', '1', 'No'], ['2', 'Install Footings', 'Building Envelope', '01/07/2022', '01/07/2022', '2', 'Yes'], ['2', 'Pouring', '', '01/08/202', '01/09/2023', '1', 'No'],['N/A', 'Pour Foundation', 'Building Envelope>Pouring', '01/08/2022', '01/09/2022', '3', 'No'], ['2', 'Installation', '', '01/09/2022', '01/14/2022', '1', 'No']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Outline_level',  'Activity', 'Parent', 'Start', 'Finish', 'WBS Level', 'Match'])

df1
```

I want to fill the N/A values in the 'Outline_Level' column with the value in the cell below it minus 1.  For example, if the cell holds an 'N/A' value, and the cell below has a value of 3, I want the N/A cell to have the value of 2.  I have tried the bfill method, which fills the N/A values but I can't figure out how to subtract one from those values.

Here is an example of my ideal dataframe:

```
Ideal_data = [['1', 'Construction', '', '01/02/2022', '01/06/2022', '1', 'No'], ['2', 'Level Site', 'Construction', '01/02/2022', '01/02/2022', '2', 'No'], ['3', 'Foundation', '', '01/03/2023', '01/06/2023', '1', 'Yes'],['2', 'Lay Foundation', 'Construction>Foundation', '01/03/2022', '01/04/2022', '3', 'No'], ['1', 'Prepare land for foundation', 'Construction>Foundation', '01/05/2022', '01/06/2022', '3', 'No'],['2', 'Building Envelope', '', '01/07/2023', '01/16/2023', '1', 'No'], ['2', 'Install Footings', 'Building Envelope', '01/07/2022', '01/07/2022', '2', 'Yes'], ['2', 'Pouring', '', '01/08/202', '01/09/2023', '1', 'No'],['1', 'Pour Foundation', 'Building Envelope>Pouring', '01/08/2022', '01/09/2022', '3', 'No'], ['2', 'Installation', '', '01/09/2022', '01/14/2022', '1', 'No']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Ideal_data, columns=['Outline_level',  'Activity', 'Parent', 'Start', 'Finish', 'WBS Level', 'Match'])

df2
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Sorry that was an error on my part @RomanPerekhrest, I just updated the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace values on recognized indices and shift values using [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
idx = df1[df1['Outline_level'].eq('N/A')].index
df1.loc[idx, 'Outline_level'] = df1['Outline_level'].shift(-1).iloc[idx].astype(int) - 1
```

---

```
  Outline_level                     Activity                     Parent  ...      Finish WBS Level Match
0             1                 Construction                             ...  01/06/2022         1    No
1             2                   Level Site               Construction  ...  01/02/2022         2    No
2             3                   Foundation                             ...  01/06/2023         1   Yes
3             2               Lay Foundation    Construction>Foundation  ...  01/04/2022         3    No
4             1  Prepare land for foundation    Construction>Foundation  ...  01/06/2022         3    No
5             2            Building Envelope                             ...  01/16/2023         1    No
6             2             Install Footings          Building Envelope  ...  01/07/2022         2   Yes
7             2                      Pouring                             ...  01/09/2023         1    No
8             1              Pour Foundation  Building Envelope>Pouring  ...  01/09/2022         3    No
9             2                 Installation                             ...  01/14/2022         1    No

[10 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution @RomanPerekhrest! It worked on my sample dataframe, but when I used it on my larger dataframe, I'm receiving the following error:  "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Level 0'".

Comment: @bcoder, this can happen when some cell holding a `N/A` value is followed by another `N/A` value, but not a number

Comment: Thank you so much @RomanPerekhrest!  I had to convert my dataframe to a numpy array to deal with the NaN (they were coming up as float values for some reason), but your code works perfectly.